# The injective objects in the category of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

What is the definition of the **injective** objects in the category of algebras?

Comment: There is a definition of injective object in any category. Do you mean to ask for examples of injective objects?

Comment: The same as in any abelian category: $I$ is injective if $\hom_{\mathrm{Alg}}(\cdot, I)$ is an exact functor.

Comment: @nik But the category of algebras is not abelian (it does not have cokernels).

Comment: @zhen Lin I just want to get the definition of injective objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An injective object in a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ is an object $I$ such that the functor $\mathcal{C} (-, I) : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ sends monomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ to surjections. To put it in simpler terms, $I$ is injective if, for every monomorphism $f : A \to B$ and every morphism $a : A \to I$, there is a morphism $b : B \to I$ such that $a = b \circ f$.

Comment: I am sorry, my major is not algebra, so could you explain what is monomorphism (any different to morphism?) to me ?

Comment: A monomorphism is a morphism $f$ with the following cancellation property: if $f \circ g = f \circ h$, then $g = h$. What this means in concrete terms depends on your category.

Comment: Thanks~ And, are you chinese? :)